# Moodle (Custom report with user custom field and feedback response)

Tags: php, mysql, database, moodle

I'm trying to develop a custom report with user custom fields and feedback.

I have a problem with the query

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT
         mdl_user.id AS Userid,
         CASE WHEN  mdl_user_info_data.fieldid=14  THEN DATA  END AS 'Level',
         mdl_feedback.course AS id_course,
         mdl_feedback_item.id AS Id_item,
         mdl_feedback_value.value AS Response
FROM mdl_feedback_value
      INNER JOIN mdl_feedback_completed ON mdl_feedback_completed.id = mdl_feedback_value.completed
        INNER JOIN mdl_user ON mdl_feedback_completed.userid = mdl_user.id 
        INNER JOIN mdl_feedback ON mdl_feedback_completed.feedback = mdl_feedback.id 
        JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id=mdl_feedback.course
        JOIN mdl_course_categories AS cc ON cc.id=c.category
        JOIN mdl_user_info_data  ON mdl_user_info_data.userid=mdl_user.id
        INNER JOIN mdl_feedback_item ON mdl_feedback_value.item = mdl_feedback_item.id 
WHERE c.idnumber IN (72007205)
AND mdl_feedback.name LIKE '%Encuesta de Cierre%'
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

The first and second result have the same `Userid` and the first result `Level` have null then the second result is with `Level` 7.

If I erase the next part of query:

```
CASE WHEN  mdl_user_info_data.fieldid=14  THEN DATA  END AS 'Level',
```

The result is correct but not have the user custom field.
[image: without Case]

Somebody can helpme to fix my query please?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the results to your question as text instead of as image. You can create table like data using code fences.

Comment: Result with case

Userid    Level        id_course       Id_item      Response
8812       NULL       108                3419           11
8812         7             108               3419           11
8812       NULL      108                  3419          2
8812         7            108                 3419          2

Without Case

Userid      id_course       Id_item      Response
8812            108               3419           11
8812            108               3419             2

Sorry, i can´t sww where can edit the question

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to just have user_info_data.fieldid as a named column, filtered, then write:

```
select 
    ...,
    user_info_data.fieldid as level,
    ...
from ...
where user_info_data.fieldid = 14 
   and c.idnumber = 72007205 
   ...
```

Alternatively, if you meant to have a choice of column (data or level), then you should use an else:

```
select 
    ...,
    case when user_info_data.fieldid = 14 then data else level end as datalevel,
    ...
```

Or for where you only want the "data" field, and also only want data associated with user_info_data.fieldid = 14:

```
select 
    ...,
    data as level,
    ...
from ...
where user_info_data.fieldid = 14 
   ...
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for you response.

In my table i have the next data:

mdl_user_info_data

id   userid   fieldid   data   dataformat
10     2           14      22         0

If i select just mdl_user_info_data.fieldid, just select 14, and i need the data "22", 
then when i put CASE WHEN  mdl_user_info_data.fieldid=14  THEN DATA  END AS 'Level', then give me the data but also give me a null element.

Comment: It sounds as though you need to have both the select case statement you originally had, as well as the where clause: where user_info_data.fieldid = 14.
The nullls are because you haven't told the server what to do in the situation where user_info_data.fieldid <> 14.